# Global Controller Variables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `ChatController` and an `@user` variable in it. On the main page I display `@user.name`. I also have destroy and create methods that work with ajax, so when I delete a message from my chat, `@user` becomes nil. To prevent problems from calling `name` on a nil object, I can add `@user=User.find_by_id(:user_id)` to every method. But this becomes tedious if I have many methods. Can I declare `@user=User.find_by_id(:user_id)` once and DRY up my code?

Comment: Your instance variables will last a single request, you can use a before filter to save repeating yourself.

Comment: @Berlin Thanks for the reply.. I just asked if any you have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is done in a `before_filter` ([Documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter)).

Something like:

```
class ChatController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :find_user


  private
  def find_user
    @user ||= User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
  end
end
```

You may also consider using [Inherited Resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) which automates this for you.